# How to be involved in paleontolgy as a non-earth scientist

Tags: paleontology, archaeology

I want to be involved in paleontology or archaeology but I don't intend to go back to school for either. I am aware of some opprotunities to volunteer on field studies but am hoping for more resources. Also, I am an analytical chemist by profession. Is this a skill that is valued in these fields that may allow me to be more involved or even get a job?

Comment: probably, although you will probably still have to do some studying on geochemistry and/or organic chemistry. Paleontology always needs more hands, find a active lab, and talk to someone is all I can offer, without a detailed description of what you can do it is difficult to offer more than generalities. This site may help, http://paleoportal.org/

Comment: I wrote once a scientifical asociation that do archaelogical excavations and was invited to dig into a deposit with heiderbengensis tools just for being a geology student. As chemist you could do age analisys. They are extremely useful. But that's maybe something you need to specialice on

Comment: they do also other trace elements studies. eg to know if a certain population came from other zone, as if you eat at different zones the trace signal is a bit different (different soils, water...)

Comment: to dig is hard for knee and young students use to do that. unpayed but good for cv. but the second year I passed there was a belgian aged 50 or so. it depends on your physical conditions. maybe tell them to work less hours. There is work to do as chemist on the lab sure. not sure how would go competence for that at your country